# Global variable changing by itself in my React Native App

Tags: javascript, react-native, variables

as you can read it on the title, I got a problem with a variable that self changes during execution of the App. The self-changing variable is **currentSlot** in the code down below :

```
var currentSlot=0;

  const setCurrentSlot = () => {
    currentSlot++;
  };

  const onSelectColor = ({ hex }) => {
    switch(currentSlot) {
      case 0:
        setcolor0(hex);
        break;
      case 1:
        setcolor1(hex);
        break;
      case 2:
        setcolor2(hex);
        break;
      case 3:
        setcolor3(hex);
        break;
      case 4:
        setcolor4(hex);
        break;
      case 5:
        setcolor5(hex);
        break;
      case 6:
        setcolor6(hex);
        break;
      case 7:
        setcolor7(hex);
        break;
      case 8:
        setcolor8(hex);
        break;
      case 9:
        setcolor9(hex);
        break;
      default:
        Alert.alert('Maximum number of colors reached (10). Tap color to delete.');
    }
  };
```

Besides, I have implemented a Color Picker, from which I can gain access to a color, and I want the latter to be displayed into a View that I displayed on the side. Ultimately, there will be a total of 10 different colors in that View component (each displayed in its tinier View).

So the idea is to iterate through the "tiny Views" thanks to variable **currentSlot** and to set their color to the one given by the color picker when I click on the "Add" button.

However while **currentSlot** is correcty incremented by function **setCurrentSlot()** (itself triggered by the "Add" button), it quickly drops down to its initial value (which is 0), and I can't seem to know why, since I am clearly doing nothing else with it.

Does someone have a idea please ?

Thanks for your help !

I tried changing my approach by using if...else statements, or switch...case. I also tried separating function in less complex ones but nothing did it good.

Comment: You need to show us where you call `setCurrentSlot`. Also, this approach with the big switch/case statement and 10 different functions is wrong --- you should use an array of colours instead, which will simplify things significantly and mean you can also store as many colours as you want, not just up to 10.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the piece of advice ! I'll make sure to improve that !

Here is where I call **setCurrentSlot**:

`<TouchableOpacity style={stylesResearchScreen.confirmSelectedColorTouchableOpacity} onPress={setCurrentSlot}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: (16/667)*Dimensions.get('window').height, fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black'}}>Add</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>`

Comment: @AntoineFotius That is a detail you should add to the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are an anti-pattern, and you shouldn't use them, especially for managing state in a React app. There's *many* reasons for this, but one which might be important here is that they're not part of the React state at all, meaning that changing a global variable doesn't trigger a re-render, so what's displayed by React will be out-of-sync with what you'd expect until something else does cause your app to re-render.

There's really not enough to go by in the question to figure out what the issue is. If you edited your question to show e.g. the full component, we might be able to fix it (and please do this in all future questions on SO!), but imo this is really an XY problem, and it would be most productive to just refactor towards something better.

---

You mention the overarching problem is:

> [I've] implemented a Color Picker, from which I can gain access to a color, and I want the latter to be displayed into a View that I displayed on the side

Ideally, we wouldn't have a seperate function for updating each of the previously selected colours: instead, we'd have one state, that they'd all read from. Something like:

```
function usePreviouslySelectedColorsState() {
  const [previouslySelectedColors, setPreviouslySelectedColors] = useState([]);

  return useMemo(() => ({
    previouslySelectedColors,
    
    addToPreviouslySelected(hex) {
      setPreviouslySelectedColors((prev) => {
        return [...prev, hex]

        // could also do "return [...prev, hex].slice(-10)" instead
        // to only ever keep the last 10
      };
    }
  }), [previouslySelectedColors]);
}
```

Now, we can use this state in our root component, both when we select a new colour, and to render the existing previously selected colours:

```
function ColorPickerWithPreviouslySelected() {
  const {
    previouslySelectedColors,
    addToPreviouslySelectedColors
  } = usePreviouslySelectedColorsState();

  return <View>
    <ColorInput onColorSelected={addColorToPreviouslySelected} />
    <PreviouslySelectedColors hexCodes={previouslySelectedColors} />
  </View>;
}
```

Where `PreviouslySelectedColors` just looks like:

```
function PreviouslySelectedColors({hexCodes}) {
  return <View>
    {
      hexCodes.map((hex) => <ColorThumbnail hex={hex} />)
    }
  </View>;
}
```

---

Besides fixing the state management so that it's driven by React and uses arrays, there's a other few patterns displayed here that I hope are helpful for you in the future:

- Each component individually should ideally do just one thing, and be as simple as it possibly can be. This means that it's easy to reuse components in the future, and to compose them together into new things. For example, the  `PreviouslySelectedColors` component here just renders colour thumbnails when given an array of hex codes --- you could use this component somewhere completely different in your app with something completely different driving that state, and it would still work perfectly fine.
- Additionally, this means splitting out more components where you can. You could have the colour input and the previous colours display all be in one big component, but splitting them apart makes each component simpler to understand individually, and like I said, more composable in general, as now they're not tied to each other or one specific state.

  - Something often useful for this is "inversion of control" --- instead of a component directly updating something (in this case, maybe the colour input could directly updating the list of previous colours), you invert the control such that the colour input doesn't know about that list at all, and just has an "event" function that it calls whenever it changes, e.g. our `onColorSelected` prop in my example. This means that the parent is free to compose the function as it needs to, without tying that logic to the component directly.